# Highcharts: Draw line from marker to axis?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am developing application using angular and very new to this high charts. I have requirement where we should draw grid line from marker to axis (as i indicated with pink arrows in attachment).
here code:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-xaxis-grid .highcharts-grid-line {
      stroke-width: 4px;
      stroke: #f2f2f2;
    }
   
   
   .highcharts-yaxis-grid .highcharts-grid-line {
      stroke-width: 2px;
      stroke: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

is the existing code. Could any one help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve something like in the above picture by rendering the custom paths from each point.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3og8w7cv/

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render() {
        let chart = this;
                
        chart.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
                    let x = p.plotX + chart.plotLeft,
                            y = p.plotY + chart.plotTop;
                    
                    if (p.customPath) {
                        p.customPath.destroy();
                    }
                    
          p.customPath = chart.renderer.path(['M', x, y, 'L', x, chart.plotSizeY + chart.plotTop])
            .attr({
              'stroke-width': 2,
              stroke: 'red'
            })
            .add();
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render